# java.util.regex

Tags: java, regex

can anyone explain to me how to identify using regexes any string that contains for example a single P character in it? Could yo also explain how this is evaluated too?

EDIT: What is the difference between `[^P*]` and `[^P]*`?

Comment: please think of a better title of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A string containing a single P character is:

- a (possibly empty) string containing non-P characters
- a P
- a (possibly empty) string containing non-P characters

In a regular expression format, this is:

```
^[^P]*P[^P]*$
```

where:

- `^` matches the start of the string
- `[^P]*` matches any character other than a P, 0 or more times
- `P` matches P
- `[^P]*` matches any character other than a P, 0 or more times
- `$` matches the end of the string

The difference between `[^P*]` and `[^P]*` is:

- `[^P*]` matches any *single* character that is neither P nor *
- `[^P]*` matches zero or more characters that are not P

The placement of the `*` is of course important here. Inside `[]`, the `*` doesn't have any special meaning. Outside `[]`, the `*` means "match the previous thing zero or more times".

Comment: That doesn't seem to work on the regex checker..? Checking Here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Then there's something wrong with your regex chaecker, @david :-) I suggest you check it on the only checker that really matters, a Java program.

Comment: what is the difference between [^P*] and [^P]*

Comment: also what is the relevance of the initial ^ ?

Comment: @david robers - of course it works with that checker. Enter some Text with a capital `P` - match. Remove that `P` - no match. Exactly as specified.

Comment: @david robers - [Everything is documented on the `Pattern` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) - please, have at look at it first.

Comment: @david robers You should probably check with Java code, for now, unless you're going to remember to escape your quotation marks in the regex patterns from RegExr.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused.. I put the above regex in and it highlights nothing in example text i provide. Should it not highlight PESDAXV, for example to indicate it has a single P.

Comment: @dr85 I just tried Greg's regex IN RegExr, and it highlights PESDAXV. Make sure you are inputting exactly Greg's pattern--with no extraneous whitespace.

Comment: @Zach - Really? Its not doing it for me. Although I have other text underneath it. It does highlight when I just put PESDAXV

Comment: @dr85 even when I put other text--next to, in front of, or under, PESDAXV, the whole thing still gets matched. Now, if you want it to just match the word that contains the P, then you're going to have to look into either matching for whitespace or word boundaries:http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html. You should rephrase your question, if that's the case.

Comment: but what happens if you put PESDAXV underneath PEWTRE

Comment: @dr85 Greg made the regex exactly for what you asked for -- matching a word that contains a *single* P.

Comment: @Zach, I understand and thats great, Im just wondering why on the regex checker only highlights one word as opposed to all words?

Comment: @dr85 Because Greg's regex will only match the whole string, since he uses ^ to indicate the beginning and $ to match the end of the string. His regex means "Between the beginning and end of the *whole* string, there is just a single P". Since it looks for the beginning and end of the string, it can't match possible matches in between,

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what you mean there? If you have PEWTRE and then on the next line PESDAXV should it not highlight both since they only contain 1 'P'? They are two seperate strings....

Comment: @dr85: does the text you're matching contain multiple lines?  If so make sure the `multiline` option is set.  If there are two lines that contain a `P`, you won't get a match because the regex is looking at the whole string.  In multiline mode it will test one line at a time.  Make sure the `global` option is set, too.

Comment: Ahhh Legend! Thanks a lot to all of u

Answer (score 2):

David, I think my answer at [one of your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703184/java-regular-expressions/4703971#4703971) will help you out. As for how it is evaluated, I'm not sure what you mean, but you might want to check out the API documentation for the [Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class.

The difference between [^P*] and [^P]* is:

- [^P*] means "one character that is not P and *"
- [^P]* means "zero or more characters that are all not P"

Comment: Hi, I couldn;t get you answer to work on the regex checker either. I'm looking at the API but it doesn;t really help you understand how the regex engine works... I.e. does it start at the beginning of a string?

Comment: Generally yes, it does start at the beginning of the string, and each subsequent call to Matcher.find() will search out the next match. Please share the name of, or what sort of, regex checker you are using so we can help you more :-).

Answer (score 1):

assuming you really want to check for a single "P". here's a non regex approach.

```
for(int i = 0 ;i< string.length(); i++){
    if ( string.charAt(i) == 'P' ){
        count++;
    }
}
if ( count == 1 ){
    System.out.println("String contains a single P");
}
```

Comment: string.contains("P") might be a slightly more simplified version :-)

Comment: well, I spoke too soon: yours makes sure that there is only one P. I take back my comment. Nevermind :-)

Comment: oh, i thought you are talking about using `containS()` in the for loop instead of `charAt()`, which i think is also valid.